# What's the real name of a prototype object?

Tags: javascript

With this:

```
console.log(String.prototype);
```

Chrome logs out:

```
String{}
```

With this:

```
console.log(String);
```

Chrome logs out:

```
function String(){ [native code] }
```

Since both `String{}` and `String()` gets the same name, why `console.log(String)` choose the function instead the object?

Comment: As answered already; the constructor function and the constructor function's prototype are not the same thing. For more information about constructor functions and prototype you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3):

> Since both `String{}` and `String()` gets the same name, why `console.log(String)` choose the function instead the object?

For obvious reasons: `String` **is** a *function* and `String.prototype` **is** an *object*. It would be rather confusing if Chrome would generate the same output for those two different values/data types.

For functions, Chrome actually shows the implementation of the function (`func.toString()`). Some functions are not implemented in JavaScript but in native code and hence you see `[native code]` instead.

For objects, Chrome takes the [name of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) (if available) [referred to by the `constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) of the object. The value of `String.prototype.constructor` is `String`.

Comment: thanks, so an object just have no it's own name? like primitive values?

Comment: In general yes. Only functions can have names.

Comment: @igonejack—Ojbects in JavaScript don't have names (Functions are Objects too), but you can assign a reference to an Object to a variable or named property of an object. So an Object can have as many names as you like, or none at all. `var a={};var b=a`. An object with two "names". `(function(){alert('hey')}())`. A function Ojbect with no name.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is the constructor (a function), `String.prototype` is, unsurprisingly, the prototype for the `String` class (`{}` in this case)

Comment: I see, you mean String in String{} isn't the name of the object but the "class", right? And the objects don't have that kind of name like functions do?